# List top N rentals for each month

Tags: mysql, aggregate, count, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to work out the SQL to list the top 5 rentals for each month on MySQL or SQL Server.  The database is the [Sakila Sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) and the table is rental. Here are the first several rows in my database client (Navicat Premium):

[image]

I'd like the take the month from the rental_date field.
Each film has a unique inventory_id.

So far I've got this:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH( rental_date ) AS month,
    inventory_id,
    COUNT ( inventory_id ) AS no_of_rentals
FROM
    rental 
GROUP BY
    MONTH ( rental_date ),
    inventory_id 
HAVING
    COUNT ( inventory_id ) > 1 
ORDER BY
    MONTH ( rental_date ),
    inventory_id;
```

Unfortunately, that returns all films with more than one rental per month, which is not what I want.

[image]

I'd like to see something more like:

```
month   inventory_id  no_of_rentals
_________________________________
April   367           5
April   98            4
(3 more rows)
May     144           5
May     32            5
(3 more rows)
etc...
```

Bonus points if you can get the film title!

Thanks!

Rob

UPDATE:

Thanks to Dominique Boucher for the answer.

Here's my finished query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
      MONTH(rental_date) rental_month_no,
      DATENAME(month, rental_date) rental_month,
      inventory_id,
      COUNT( inventory_id ) no_of_rental,
      ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY MONTH(rental_date) ORDER BY COUNT( inventory_id ) DESC) Rank
    FROM
      rental 
    GROUP BY
      MONTH(rental_date),
      DATENAME(month, rental_date),
      inventory_id 
    HAVING COUNT( inventory_id ) > 1
) 
SELECT
    rental_month,
    cte.inventory_id,
    title,
    no_of_rental,
    rank
FROM
  cte
  JOIN inventory ON cte.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
  JOIN film ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id
WHERE
  Rank < 6
ORDER BY rental_month_no, no_of_rental DESC;
```

I added code to fetch the titles and limited results to films that were rented more than once in a month.

Here are the results in Navicat:

[image]

Comment: See added tag.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pretty much the same script in a CTE but add the row number (partition by month).
This will return all rows with a row number in front, reseting at 1 for every month. Then you can just issue your query with a "where rn <=5" and that will make it.

Here's an example just to give you a starting point:

```
create table #Demo (Rental_id int identity, rental_month int, inventoryId int, customer_id int)

insert into #Demo values (2,556,495),(2,236,495),(2,116,495),(2,556,495),(2,556,495),(2,116,495),(2,323,495),(2,56,495),(2,49,495),(2,49,495),
(2,116,495),(2,556,495),(2,453,495),(2,236,495),(2,34,495),(2,116,495),(2,556,495),(2,556,495),(2,24,495),(2,24,495)

insert into #Demo values (3,117,495),(3,236,495),(3,117,495),(3,236,495),(3,117,495),(3,116,495),(3,117,495),(3,236,495),(3,117,495),(3,236,495),
(3,116,495),(3,556,495),(3,453,495),(3,236,495),(3,34,495),(3,117,495),(3,556,495),(3,556,495),(3,117,495),(3,24,495),(3,34,495)

go


with cte as (
select rental_month, inventoryId, COUNT(inventoryId) "no_of_rental", ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by rental_month order by count(inventoryId)) "RN"
from #Demo
group by rental_month, inventoryId
)
select * from cte where RN <6;


drop table #Demo
```